# What to check if PharData::buildFromDirectory fails to write contents of a file to a tar?

Tags: php, exception, tar, phar

I have a background script which generates html files (ea 100-500KB in size) as a by-product and when it has accumulated 500 of them, it packs them up in a .tar.gz and archives them. It was running non-stop for several weeks and generated 131 .tar.gz files thus far until this morning when it threw the following exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'tar-based phar
"E:/xampp/.../archive/1394109645.tar" cannot be created, contents of file 
"58836.html" could not be written' in E:/xampp/.../background.php:68
```

The code responsible for archiving

```
$name = $path_archive . $set . '.tar';
$archive = new PharData($name);
$archive->buildFromDirectory($path_input); // <--- line 68
$archive->compress(Phar::GZ);
unset($archive);
unlink($name);            
array_map('unlink', glob($path_input . '*'));
```

What I've checked and made sure of so far

- I couldn't find anything irregular in the html file itself,
- nothing else was touching this file during the process,
- scripts timeout and memory were unlimited
- and enough spare memory and disk space

What could be causing the exception and/or is there a way to get a more detailed message back from `PharData::buildFromDirectory`?

Env: Virtual XP (in VirtualBox) running portable XAMPP (1.8.2, PHP 5.4.25) in a shared folder of a Win7 host

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem after hours of bug-hunting today. It was caused by too little space on one partition of the disk. I had enough space in the partition where `tar.gz` archive was created but after removing some log files from another partition everything works again.

I think it's possible that object `PharData` stores some temporary data somewhere and that's why this is happening even if there is enough space on the disk where you create `tar.gz` archive.

Comment: Looked into it but found that I'm currently running on a single partition disk. I have a feeling the problem might be caused by the env I've got running - if the VirtualBox shared folder plugin has a glitch it surely could make a dent in the writing process